# Buildozer can't compile Cython when I add from jnius import *

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm trying to build android application via Kivy. First, I tried to run *buildozer android debug* with code:

```
__version__=="1.0"
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class HelloApp(App):
    def build(self):
         return Button(text='Hello')

if __name__=='__main__':
    HelloApp().run()
```

I did feel happy when it worked. And I successfully test it on phone. Then, I tried to add *from injnius....* to this code to develop native application. This new code:

```
__version__=="1.0"
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from jnius import autoclass

BluetoothApdapter=autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter') # example...


class HelloApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello')

if __name__=='__main__':
   HelloApp().run()
```

Then I ran line command  *buildozer android debug* . It didn't work. And this is log errror:

```
 jnius/jnius_utils.pxi:188:45: Obtaining char* from temporary Python value
 /home/mylap/Desktop/Hello2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
 warnings.warn(msg)
 running build_ext
 building 'jnius' extension
 arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -fPIC -I/home/mylap/Desktop/Hello2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/jnius/jnius.o
jnius/jnius.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
#error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
^error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Then, I tried to solve it with some solution such as :

```
pip install cython=={version: 0.17.1, 0.20, 0.19}
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cython-dev/master-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cython
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade cython
```

But, it still doesn't work. I'm using: Unbutun 14( 32 bit on VWM), Python 2.7, Kivy version 1.7.

Comment: Not sure what's happening here since pyjnius is included automatically (and so was in your original build that worked), and buildozer doesn't check/care that you import it. However, the error relates to some recent changes that I did think involved a cython issue.